# SIGINT when transforming a std::string to upper case?

Tags: c++

A program I'm debugging is receiving SIGINT at this point:

```
#0  0x00007ffff590784e in toupper () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

The code in question is this:

```
std::string search = name;
std::transform(search.begin(), search.end(), search.begin(), ::toupper);
```

Right now I don't know whats the content, but special symbols are allowed.

I already got that I'm doing something wrong here, sinse its actually UTF-8 and I should be converting it to `std::wstring` before performing case transformations. Howover, even though I was doing it the wrong way I don't understand why it should crash.

What are the reasons for `toupper` to crash for SIGINT? And how can I avoid that some user input can this to my server application?

Answer (score 2):

UTF-8 uses numbers that will appear negative when viewed as a signed char (which is the usual). Giving those negative numbers to `toupper` gives undefined behavior.

Try:

```
std::transform(search.begin(), search.end(), search.begin(), 
    [](unsigned char ch) {return ::toupper(ch); });
```

...and see if things don't work a little better.

Comment: The lambda expression can be written nicer, though: `[](unsigned char c){ return toupper(c); }`